# is it possible to check me in converting c# code to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c# sharp code and I wanted to convert it to javascript code.

the following code is the c# code:

```
    public static void QuadKeyToTileXY(string quadKey, out int tileX, out int tileY, out int levelOfDetail)  
    {  
        tileX = tileY = 0;  
        levelOfDetail = quadKey.Length;  
        for (int i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)  
        {  
            int mask = 1 << (i - 1);  
            switch (quadKey[levelOfDetail - i])  
            {  
                case '0':  
                    break;  

                case '1':  
                    tileX |= mask;  
                    break;  

                case '2':  
                    tileY |= mask;  
                    break;  

                case '3':  
                    tileX |= mask;  
                    tileY |= mask;  
                    break;  

                default:  
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid QuadKey digit sequence.");  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

}

and I tried to convert it to java script in this form :

```
function quadKeyToTileXY(quadKey) {
        tileX = tileY = 0;  
        levelOfDetail = quadKey.Length;  
        for (int i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)  
        {  
            int mask = 1 << (i - 1);  
            switch (quadKey[levelOfDetail - i])  
            {  
                case '0':  
                    break;  

                case '1':  
                    tileX |= mask;  
                    break;  

                case '2':  
                    tileY |= mask;  
                    break;  

                case '3':  
                    tileX |= mask;  
                    tileY |= mask;  
                    break;  

                default:  
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid QuadKey digit sequence.");  
            }  
        }  
    } 
}
```

I want to know is it any mistake in my code? is it possible to correct me if I have mitakes.

Comment: did you defined `tileX` `tileY` variables in your JavaScript code globally. if not, then i think you have to initialize them.

Comment: You didn't convert this code to javascript, you just copied and pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function quadKeyToTileXY(quadKey) {
        let tileX = 0 ;
        let tileY = 0;  
        const levelOfDetail = quadKey.Length;  
        for (let i = levelOfDetail; i > 0; i--)  
        {  
            let mask = 1 << (i - 1);  
            switch (quadKey[levelOfDetail - i])  
            {  
                case '0':  
                break;  

                case '1':  
                    tileX |= mask;  
                    break;  

                case '2':  
                    tileY |= mask;  
                    break;  

                case '3':  
                    tileX |= mask;  
                    tileY |= mask;  
                    break;  

                default:  
                    throw new Error("Invalid QuadKey digit sequence.");  
            }  
        }  
    } 
}
```